# Grep for pattern in first occurrence of XML element

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have a file with multiple occurrences of an XML element. I want to grep for a pattern *only in the first element*. I want to use `grep` because I need to use this as the condition of an `if` check in a bash script. NOTE that unfortunately, I am not guaranteed that the XML element(s) are contained in an enclosing tag (this file is generated by another program out of my control).

### Example of a match for "mango"

```
 <element>
       apple
       banana
       orange
       mango
 </element>
 <element>
       apple
       banana
       orange
       mango
 </element>
```

### Example of a non-match for "mango"

In the following XML snippet, I want my search to fail b/c `mango` doesn't exist in the first element.

```
 <element>
       apple
       banana
       orange
 </element>
 <element>
       apple
       banana
       orange
       mango
 </element>
```

Comment: Could you provide a syntactically valid XML? you could `xmllint` with `xpath` to approach towards using a more syntax aware parsers. `sed`/`grep` do not know the underlying file syntax

Comment: unfortunately, I am not guaranteed that the XML element(s) are contained in an enclosing tag (this file is generated by another program out of my control).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved this, but I had to use a pipe combining `grep` with `sed`. This solution only worked for me because the first `<element>` is on the first line of the file.

`sed -n '0,/<\/element>/p' /path/to/file | grep -q mango`

1. Uses `sed` to print the first line of the file up to the first closing tag for `element`.
2. Uses `grep` to exit true or false if it matches `mango`.

Comment: @choroba: Does this look as valid xml? Look at OkieOths solution, which doesn't work. See, how easy to maintain this short one liner is and compare yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This may be quite a lengthy solution, however it works.

```
./check.sh mango
```

This calls a simple awk script for each file, referenced by the FILES variable

note:
The xml files I saved as: `xml1`, `xml2`

For the example above, it produces the following output:
`mango found in xml1`
`mango not found in xml2`

is-here.awk:

```
BEGIN {
  tagOpened="not yet"
  tagsPresent=0
}

/<[[:alnum:]]+>/ {
  if (tagsPresent <= 1)   # remove this condition to check ALL occurencies
  {
    tagOpened="true"
    tagsPresent++
  }
}

/<[/][[:alnum:]]+>/ {
  tagOpened="false"
}

// {
  if (match($1, value) && tagOpened=="true" && length($1)==length(value))
  {
    found++
  }
}

END {

  if (found == tagsPresent)
  {
    print "present"
  }
  else
  {
    print "not"
  }
}
```

check.sh

```
#! /bin/bash

function check()
{
  local file=$1
  local pattern=$2
  local result=$(cat $file | gawk -f is-here.awk -v value=$pattern)
  echo $result
}

FILES="xml1 xml2"

for file in $FILES
do
  result=$(check $file $1)

  if [ "$result" == "present" ]
  then
    echo "$1 found in $file"
  else
    echo "$1 not found in $file"
  fi  
done
```

Comment: This doesn't look for 'element'. And couldn't the end-block in the awk script just `print ("found==tagsPresent")`, making it a swee oneliner? The file masking is curious too. Declared at one line, used only once - that's cargo cult programming and bad filename masking too.

Comment: This looks for any tag. Output message is just for readability

Comment: And "searchFor" in the awk?

Comment: it's variable which is passed to gawk: -v value=$pattern for more general usage

Comment: But in gawk, you use `value`, not `searchFor`. It's an unused variable.

Answer (score 0):

For the handling of XML data I would always recommend XML tools. Only that tools can handle the specifics of XML in a save way. For the commandline is a tool called xsltproc available. This is a simple to use XSLT processor and it can do the job better than sed. The only drawback you need an additional xslt stylesheet.

Example stylesheet: test.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">
        <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="element[position()=1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*|@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the stylesheet and xsltproc you can do a command like this

```
xsltproc test.xslt test.xml | grep mango
```

Comment: I get `mango:7: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
<element>
^
unable to parse mango`, caret below '<' before element, line 7 (or 6) is the second element block in both files.

Comment: @userunknown the example xml in that question isn't valid ... that seems me the reason for the error. I wrap it in extra tags and put it in a file called test.xml